# Unable to connect database to web administration tool 2010

Tags: asp.net

Im using web developer 2010 and unable to connect my database to the web administration tools.
Whenever i register a new member, the data is not saved into the web administration tools.

Is it because of the:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="xxxConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=rainbowinthedar\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

or

```
<membership>
        <providers>
          <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
          <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
               type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
               connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
               minRequiredPasswordLength="5"
               minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
               passwordAttemptWindow="10"
               passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
               />
        </providers>
      </membership>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string names do not match. I guess it is being saved to different databases.

```
name="xxxConnectionString"
```

vs

```
connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
```

Comment: by right i should change it the connectionStringName="xxxConnectionString" right?

Comment: @user1434463: From what I can see, yes.